# node oracledb connection pool refresh

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I have maintained a connection pool to oracle database (cluster) by nodeJS & 'oracledb' module.

From database side, seems that the pool connections are not balanced between two dbs under the cluster.

1. Any suggestion how to fix that?
2. Also, do I need to refresh the pool time by time? or just leave the pool there forever?
3. For point 2, I have 'manually' refresh the pool by creating a new duplicate pool for connection and kill the old one for every 'x' mins. And turns out I encounter an error called: ORA-12549: TNS:operating system resource quota exceeded, may I know why?

Appreciate if you can solve my confusion, thanks.

Comment: I assume your cluster is RAC.  Turn on Load Balancing advisory notifications at your database service, and also use the `events` mode when you create the connection pool.  Avoid "refreshing" the pool.  Your resource error is probably because you have tried to open too many concurrent connections to the DB.  You might want to check your connect descriptor, e.g see examples in https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/clustering/checklist-ac-6676160.pdf

Comment: @ChristopherJones thx for the advice, will definitely try your approach and update here once I get the result!

Comment: The actual numbers of connections to each node of the cluster shouldn't matter as long as the connection pool's runtime load balancing (RLB) feature is dispensing SQL statements appropriately across the connections to the nodes.